# Мерцание при обновлении списка notifyDataSetChanged для адаптера Listview (Android)

Tags: java, android

Есть лента новостей, в которую подгружаются посты (с картинками, текстами, аватрками авторов и т.д.). Посты подгружаются пачками по мере прокрутки.

Использую Listview и BaseAdapter. В BaseAdapter использую паттерн ViewHolder.
Имеется также класс для хранения данных поста и все посты добавляются в список List <PostsData   > list. Из этого списка адаптер берёт посты.

`adapter = new PostAdapter(HomeActivity.this, list);
            contentLV.setAdapter(adapter);`

Затем при подгрузке новой пачки постов я просто добавляю все посты в список list и вызываю `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. При этом происходит мерцание (на долю секунды получается такое как моргание). Это не критично, но не очень приятно выглядит.

Также, у каждого поста есть кнопка лайков, при нажатии на которую на сервер отправляется запрос. При получении ответа в списке list обновляется определённая позиция, где был поставлен лайк (т.е. я извлекаю нужный пост и ставлю новое количество лайков и то что лайк поставлен, а потом обратно заношу в этот список с текущим индекосм). После этого я снова вызываю метод `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` и происходит моргание. Хотя если тут же (не прокручивая список) снова нажать лайк (чтобы удалить его) при обновлении уже не происходит моргания.

Comment: Мерцают картинки?

Comment: @Андроид Андроид да, картинки. Забыл также упомянуть, что использую Universal Image Loader для отображения и загрузки картинок.

Comment: Скажу лишь, что я решил проблему перейдя на picasso, и вам советую также поступить)

Comment: @Андроид Андроид да я бы может и использовал её, но там дольше грузятся картинки почему-то. UIL практически мгновенно выводит, а пикасо с задержкой небольшой.

Comment: Сранно, у меня вплоть наоборот)

Comment: @Андроид Андроид Ну тогда попозже попробую заменить на Picasso.

Comment: @Андроид Андроид попробовал сегодня поменять на Picasso, но от этого стало только дольше мерцание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот, мы плавно подошли к RecyclerView =) 
RecyclerView позволяет обновлять не всю пачку данных, а нужное количество. 1 и более элементов могут быть обновлены методом [notifyItemChanged](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int)) или notifyItemRangeChanged для подмножества, соответственно. Как раз когда количество лайков будет меняться, будет обновлен только 1 item "ресайклера". 
Поведение по дефолту, предусматривает дефолтную анимацию, по-этому итем будет все равно анимирован, после вызова метода *notifyItemChanged*. Чтобы этого не происходило, нужно заоверрайдить класс аниматора RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.

Возможно есть и другие способы, более простые способы, но я о них незнаю. =)

Comment: Вот это уже как раз то что нужно) Но к сожалению сейчас некогда попробовать, но когда руки дойдут, обязательно использую RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, это происходит, потому что обновляются все данные и UIL заново устанавливает картинку (уже из кеша, конечно же).
Как вариант, это можно решить переходом на RecyclerView и использованием такой штуки как ["Пагинация"](https://medium.com/@etiennelawlor/pagination-with-recyclerview-1cb7e66a502b#.efqti9672)
В общем советую погуглить в этом направлении, думаю что то полезное для себя найдете.

Comment: В дальнейшем попробую RecyclerView, если не поможет решение выше про использование Picasso.
А о пагинации не может быть и речи. Посты должны подгружаться бесконечно, как в вк например, или в инстаграмме.

Comment: В vk и instagrame **используется** пагинация, просто она визуально немного отличается от, возможно, вам привычной. Конечно же, подгрузка данных происходит, когда юзер превысил порог, например 60% просмотренного. Вот попробуйте войти в ВК с устройства, подождать пока загрузиться пачка данных и отключите интернет. Доскролив до конца можно обнаружить, что новая пачка данных не догрузилась, как раз таки при помощи пагинации =))

Comment: тогда может быть я не правильно понимаю что такое пагинация. По моему представлению пагинация - это разбитие на страницы. Т.е. это старый классический метод, который был на форумах и всяких сайтах - просмотрел штук 10-20 постов, перешёл на следующую страницу к следующим 10-20 постам. В вк же автопагинация, т.е. там нет разбития на страницы, там прокрутил до самого низа, подгрузились следующие посты. И если отрубить инет, и долистать до самого низа в вк, то там просто написано "не удалось загрузить данные".

Comment: Да, то что вы наблюдаете в vk — это и есть пагинация. Бесконечный скролл, автоматически ростущий список :)
Именно такую штуку вы хотите получить, сюдя по заданному вопросу. Блин, да такой способ отображения данных применяется везде, повсеместно. Я даже затрудняюсь назвать приложение, где этот паттерн напрашивается, но его нет...

Comment: ну так я и использую пагинацию значит)) Запускается активити, загружается 30 постов, пользователь прокручивает их до конца и загружается ещё 20 постов, потом опять прокручивает до конца и ещё 20 постов и так до бесконечности.
Проблема в том, что когда один из постов изменяется (меняется количество лайков и картинка лайка), то обновляются все данные, из-за чего и происходит мерцание. Мне кажется если бы был способ обновлять не все данные, а только один или несколько постов, то это бы решило проблему, но в BaseAdapter этого нет, а как такой метод написать я не знаю.